# How to assign list of widgets as a child of Column?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of Widgets and I want to use it as one of the children of a Column. Like this:

```
List<Widget> wList = [];
Column(
    children([
        Text("hi"),
        //elements of wlist
    ])
)
```

I want to map it to use elements of list. What would be the syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

3 dots operator will solve it shortly ... Try it like this

```
 List<Widget> wList = []; // add your widgets here
    Column(
        children([
            Text("hi"),
            ...wList
        ])
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add it as

```
Column(
 children: wList,
);
```

If you need additional widgets in said column with widget list you can always use it like:

```
 Column(
     children: [add widgets here] + wList,
    );
```

Or the other way around to add list before widgets in the column.

Answer (score 0):

You pass the list of widgets into a **named argument** called children.
The syntax would be:

```
    Column(
       children: <Widget>[Text('Hello'), Text('World')]
       )
```

With named arguments, you write the name of the argument and then a colon (:) and then the value you want to pass.